# A box in packaging

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german, word-choice, single-word-request

We're currently revising translations for packaging machines. Box goes in, product goes in, box filled with product goes out. Confusion has risen whether to use *Karton*, *Kiste*, *Schachtel*, *Kasten* or something different altogether for the word "box". They seem quite similar to each other.

Sentences will be short and displayed on industrial interfaces.

Example usage:

1. > Products per box
2. > Batches per box
3. > Box dimensions
4. > Door near box pusher is open

Current translations:

1. > Produkte pro Karton
2. > Chargen pro Karton
3. > Kartonabmessungen
4. > Tür am Kartonschieber ist geoffnet

Because a pictures says more than a thousand words:

[image: Boxes]

Boxes like that. Folded packaging boxes, possibly a bit more heavy duty than the ones in the picture.

Are we using *Karton* correctly here? If not, what would be the better alternative?

Comment: What you're picturing here are *Kartons*. *Schachteln* are smaller and usually have simple, not corrugated cardboard walls. *Kisten* have walls made from something stronger, such as plastics or even wood.

Comment: I have no idea, what *box pusher* could mean, since it seems to have a door nearby- I would associate the word with a person (similar to *Sokoban* game). Perhaps *Transportarm* is intended?

Comment: @guidot A plate on a cylinder pushing the box. An extendable arm if you will. The door is to keep personel out and has nothing to do with the box itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## For this application: Stay with *Box*, do not use *Karton*

There are differences possible with all the choices of German words presented, true. These differences between *Schachtel, Karton, Kiste, Kasten* are already detailed in other answers. Other candidates in the same direction might be *Packung*, *Päckchen*.

However, one aspect overlooked so far is the actual situation where this has to be adapted to. In an industrial application there are other factors to consider than Germanic pureness in language. These factors have to do with international communications, ergonomics and just plain display length available. German equivalents to perfectly understandable English words in user interfaces are quite often much longer when display size is limited.

It is therefore perhaps something between *perfectly* acceptable to actually the better choice to leave this word almost untranslated: with **Box** (the translation here being the capitalisation). To drive it home: The word *Box is a German word.*

This is easy to confirm by looking into the venerable Duden:

> 3b – kastenförmiger Behälter –– [Duden: Box](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Box)

In case some purists want to object to that choice, as they feel this to be some kind of Denglisch infringement: It's at least not a recent invader into Germanic purity of language:

> 5. b)  kastenförmiger Behälter
>
> Box f. ‘abgeteilter Raum, kastenförmiger Behälter’, **im Dt. seit der 1. Hälfte des 19. Jhs.**, beruht auf Entlehnung von engl. box ‘Büchse, Kasten, abgesonderter Platz’. Dieses setzt aengl. box ‘Büchse, Behälter aus Buchsbaumholz’ fort, das sich wie dt. ↗Büchse (s. d.) über spätlat. und mlat. bezeugtes buxis (oder mlat. buxa?, vgl. FEW 9, 655) von lat. pyxis, griech. pyxís (πυξίς) ‘Büchse (aus Buchsbaumholz)’ herleiten läßt.
>
> [DWDS.de –– Box, die](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Box)

Anyone still skeptical might consult ["Rechtschreibung in der Box"](https://www.mildenberger-verlag.de/page.php%3Fmodul%3DGoShopping%26op%3Dshow_article%26aid%3D6019%26cid%3D347), "Rechtschreibung in der Box – Lernkärtchen mit Strategie(n), Klasse 3" that should be easy enough.

That gives you much more display real estate:

> ```
> Products per box
> Produkte pro Karton 
> Produkte pro Box
>
> Batches per box
> Chargen pro Karton
> Chargen pro Box
>
> Box dimensions
> Kartonabmessungen
> Boxengrößen
>
> Door near box pusher is open
> Tür am Kartonschieber ist geöffnet
> Tür am Boxenschieber is offen
> ```

If anyone wants to object to this analysis on absolute grounds, like

> Nur ist mit einer deutschen Box etwas anderes gemeint als mit dem englischen Wort box, wie deine Duden- und DWDS-Auszüge zeigen. In keinem Fall jedenfalls Verpackungskartons.

Then she might [perform a net search](https://www.google.com/search?q=verpackungsboxen) for actual usage and discover numerous examples:

> [hochwertige Verpackungsbox halb geschlossen](https://www.schlender.de/verpackung/klappschachtel/595-hochwertige-verpackungsbox-halb-geschlossen.html)
>   Produkttags:
>
> **Box,** Schuber, Verpackungsbox halb geschlossen, Box geschlossen, ohne Mechanik, Ordnerbox, Kartonage, Produkte, Rahmenteil, Verpackungsbox mit Konturstanzung, Niete
>   [image]

This might be quite instructive if looking at the categories chosen by https://www.verpackungswelt.de

- Geschenkboxen >

  - Magnetboxen
  - Stülpdeckelkartonagen
  - Kragencartonagen
  - Schuberkartonagen
  - Box mit Schleife

The site Verpackungsplus has categorised this thing:

> [image]
>   as [Produktinformationen](https://www.verpackungplus.de/colompac/euroboxen/5876/1002-0107?c=382) "**Euroboxen** S, 145x95x140mm, CP154.151015"

One thing to consider: a *Box* can be made of anything, it is quite generic in describing make, size and material. But *[Karton](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Karton)* quite strongly implies that it is made from thicker paper. Depending on how "sturdy" the boxes you use are – be it laminated, from plastic etc. – the Karton may be not the best choice after all.
These differences are all *not* absolutes but have quite subtle tendencies in meaning.

#### Conclusion

You may use any of the alternatives, but *Box* itself just 'ticks the most boxes' on any checklist, giving you numerous advantages:
 Every German user should be able to understand the meaning of *Box*. From the alternatives available, *Box* is the shortest native word that has also a larger field of possible applications.

Although there are multiple solutions to this one problem, there is not *the* on and only correct solution. I think *Box* is perfectly fine. You are free to choose. This is nicely illustrated with this offer on Amazon:

> [Schachteln aus Karton 55 x 45 x 45 cm – Verpackung, Boxen aus Pappe](https://www.amazon.de/Schachteln-Karton-Verpackung-Boxen-Pappe/dp/B01I3JAL0I)

<sub>If you feel that using *Box* makes your display too short or not enough German sounding or looking, you may opt for a nice compound word in your last example: "Boxenschiebertür is geöffnet".</sub>

Comment: Nur ist mit einer *deutschen Box* etwas anderes gemeint als mit dem englischen Wort *box*, wie deine Duden- und DWDS-Auszüge zeigen. In keinem Fall jedenfalls Verpackungskartons.

Answer (score 10):

What you have there is best described as **Kartons**.

> Products per box — Artikel je/pro Karton

The plural *die Produkte* usually means *different kinds of items*. In your case, you may want to use **Artikel** instead. The latin word *pro* is widely understood in German, though the more natural German term is *je*.

> Batches per box — Chargen je/pro Karton

Same with *je* or *pro*.

> Box dimensions — Kartonabmessungen

Correct.

> Door near box pusher is open — Tür am Kartonschiebegerät ist ge**ö**ffnet.

I understand this is a machine pushing the boxes forward. But **Schieber** unfortunately has a second meaning in German, it also means **slider**. Which may be understood as some wrinkle on the box. Better add **-gerät** to make sure it's understood the box pusher is meant.

---

Long story:

> Karton

A cardboard box of unspecified size and strength, for example a *Schuhkarton* (shoebox). Also the name for cardboard as a material.

> Kiste

A crate, made of wood or metal, more durable than regular cardboard. May be an extra-strong cardboard box. *Pappkiste* (cardboard crate) is a compound word people may invent on the spot if the difference is important.

> Schachtel

A small box used for shipping and for storing items that are easily broken. *Hutschachtel* comes to mind, but also *Schuhschachtel*. Used also for boxes inside bigger boxes. The verb  *verschachteln* means *to put things into things.*

> Kast**en**

A cuboid-shaped item. Not necessarily a box. Often used as a derogatory of questionable design or appraisal for sheer size (if nothing else). If used to describe a box, it's a rather tough one.

Answer (score 7):

As Kilian Foth said in his comment, *Karton* is the best word to use here.

A *Schachtel* is generally too small (usually smaller than a shoe box), a *Kiste* (or a *Kasten*) usually made from more solid material (like wood) -- that would be a *chest* or a *crate*.

While *Kartons* can come in different sizes, they would normally be compounded to indicate that, as in *Schuhkarton* (*shoe box*) or *Umzugskarton* (box used when packaging things up for moving house). Without any modifier I would assume them to be about the sizes shown on your photo.

Answer (score 5):

I would use *Karton*, because that's what we're seeing in the picture. Kartons can be of different size, so if you're using solely carboard boxes, *Karton* is correct.

*Kiste* means *crate* and ist mostly made of plastic or wood.
*Schachtel* would be much smaller and of thinner cardboard.

Answer (score -3):

As a native speaker I would just use the word ***Box***.

- ***Kiste*** is more likely something with a hard woodenlike casematerial.
- ***Kartons*** are those pictured. But *Box* could be used too in a more general way.
- ***Schachtel*** is more like a little *Karton-Box* where your shoes are packed inside when buying new shoes.
- ***Kaste***: I wouldn't recommend to use this word as it is not used for boxes.

Comment: And of course, it is *Kasten*, not *Kaste*.

Comment: A _Schachtel_ is generally smaller than a _Schuhkarton_.

Comment: Soweit ist die Denglisierung glücklicherweise dann doch noch nicht fortgeschritten, als dass "Box" für solche Fälle der Standard-Ausdruck wäre

Comment: Nicht der Standard-Ausdruck aber wohl doch sehr generell und akzeptable